# Physics Based Multiplayer Game

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development, multiplayer, real-time-multiplayer

I would like to ask:

If anyone can explain the logic and architecture behind multiplayer physics-based games.

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During my own research about this topic, I came across these three resources and I would read them (if at all) in the following order. You will see a lot of names dropped which enable you to do further investigation:

1. [Making Fast-Paced Multiplayer Networked Games Is Hard](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8399767)
2. [UE4 networking slides](https://cedric-neukirchen.net/Downloads/Compendium/UE4_Network_Compendium_by_Cedric_eXi_Neukirchen.pdf)
3. [Method for simulating newtonian interactions over a computer network](https://patents.google.com/patent/US5623642A/en)

In general, you will almost always have to **mix** several approaches to achieve the best illusion of a multi player world presence.